# How to split a div into two columns as we split a table?

Tags: html, css

I actually wanted the two grids in one div , I mean one grid in right, other in the left .....but for now the grid is appearing down. Its same as you split in a table with two rows !! same as that I need to split a div and add two grids side by side . Hope you get my point . Thanking you all in advance for your awesome support and replies

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create two divs inside your main div

```
<div id="main">
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

With CSS, fix each one to the correct side

```
#left { float:left }
#right { float:right }
```

Comment: This will not behave as a table. You wont be able to make left and right 100% height.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on the design you want to achieve for that table. There are multiple approaches, each of them yielding slightly different results.

1. You can change the [`display`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp) CSS property on the divs. The best value to use would be `table-cell`; however, this value is not supported by any version of IE. You can also try `inline` or `inline-block` values.
2. You can make the divs float to the left in their container.
3. You can use absolute or relative positioning of the divs in their container; however, that approach doesn't work well with fluid designs.
4. You can switch to `span`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expansion of Omar Abid's accepted answer. I started with that and had to make further modifications so it would work in my example of the stated question.

I made this work with class names instead of IDs so I could call the same CSS in multiple instances. This gave me the the ability to simulate two equal size cells. In my example, I set fixed size with ems so that it could preserve its appearance cross a range of table and desktop browser sizes (in my mobile CSS, I have a different strategy).

To align an image in the left div, I had to make a separate block (the last one in the CSS code).

This should address the question in most instances

```
    <div class="BrandContainer">
        <div class="BrandContainerTitle">
            <h1>...</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="BrandContainerImage">
            <img alt="Demo image" src="..." />
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .BrandContainer
{
    width: 22em;
}
.BrandContainerTitle
{
    vertical-align: top;
    float: right;
    width: 10em;
}
.BrandContainerImage
{
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}
.BrandContainerImage img
{
    width: 10em;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a table. It makes more sense to use tables where they are more efficient. Things like that is what tables are made for, and div is not made for.